# Result consisted of more than one row - Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this error message:

`Result consisted of more than one row`
but I check my procedure again and again but I cannot find any problem:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_Fetch_Returned_With_Serials;
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Fetch_Returned_With_Serials`()
BEGIN

    DECLARE Num BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE __Product_Id bigint UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE __Serials varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;



    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT product_id, serials FROM tmp_table_returned_product_serial;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    START TRANSACTION ;

    SET  @Document_Id = 0 ;
    SET @Product_Id = 0;
    SET @Payment_Amount = 0;

    OPEN cur;
    read_loop:
    LOOP


        IF done
        THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH cur INTO __Product_Id,__Serials;

        CALL SP_Separate_Numeric_Values(`__Serials`);

        SET @Is_Returnable = 0;
        SET @Level_Id = 0;
        SET @Free_Day = 0;
        SET @Penalty_Percent = 0;
        SET @Factor_Type_Id = 0;
        SET @Currency_Id = 0;
        SET @Customer_Id = 0;
        SET @Factor_Id = 0;

        SET @Value = 0;
        SET @Real_Fee = 0;
        SET @Date_At = CURRENT_DATE();
        SET @Diff_Days = 0;
        SET @New_Factor_Id = 0;
        SET @New_Detail_Factor_Id = 0;
        SET @Receipt_Remit_Type_Id = 0;
        SET @Return_Penalty_Percent = 0;
        SET @Return_Penalty_Price = 0;
        SET @Document_Number = 0;



        SELECT id INTO @Factor_Type_Id FROM Tb_Factor_Types WHERE name = 'back_sale_factor';

        SELECT COUNT(NV.Number) INTO @Value FROM Numeric_Values NV;

        SELECT TP.is_returnable,
               TU.level_id,
               currency_id,
               customer_id,
               VF.id,
               VF.product_id,
               real_fee,
               date_at
        INTO @Is_Returnable,@Level_Id,@Currency_Id,@Customer_Id,@Factor_Id,@Product_Id,@Real_Fee,@Date_At
        FROM Vw_Factor_Master_Details VF
                 INNER JOIN Tb_Factor_Detail_Serials TFDS ON TFDS.detail_id = VF.detail_id
                 INNER JOIN Tb_Products TP ON VF.product_id = TP.id
                 INNER JOIN Tb_Users TU ON TU.user_id = VF.customer_id
                 INNER JOIN Numeric_Values NV ON NV.Number = TFDS.serial_id;

        IF (@Is_Returnable)
        THEN

            SET @Product_Title = '';
            SET @Error_Msg = '';

            SELECT IFNULL(TPT.title, TP.title_en) AS title INTO @Product_Title FROM Tb_Products TP
                              LEFT JOIN (SELECT title, product_id FROM Tb_Product_Translations WHERE locale = @Locale) TPT
                                        ON TP.id = TPT.product_id WHERE product_id = @Product_Id;
            SELECT message INTO @Error_Msg FROM Tb_Errors WHERE error_code = 1000028 AND locale = @Locale;

            SET @Error_Msg = REPLACE(@Error_Msg, ':product', @Product_Title);
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @Error_Msg;

        END IF;


        SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), @Date_At) INTO @Diff_Days;


        SELECT MAX(`number`) INTO Num FROM Tb_Factors WHERE year_id = @Fiscal_Year AND type = 'sale_factor';
        SET Num = ifnull(Num, 0) + 1;


        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(TS.value, CONCAT('$.', @Level_Id)), '$.free_day')
        INTO @Free_Day
        FROM Tb_Settings TS
        WHERE `key` = 'returned_product';
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(TS.value, CONCAT('$.', @Level_Id)), '$.penalty_percent')
        INTO @Penalty_Percent
        FROM Tb_Settings TS
        WHERE `key` = 'returned_product';


        IF (@Diff_Days > @Free_Day)
        THEN
            SET @Payment_Amount = @Payment_Amount + ((@Real_Fee - (@Real_Fee * @Penalty_Percent / 100)) * @Value);
            SET @Return_Penalty_Percent = @Penalty_Percent;
            SET @Return_Penalty_Price = @Real_Fee * @Penalty_Percent / 100;
        END IF;

        IF(@New_Factor_Id = 0)
        THEN
            INSERT INTO Tb_Factors (type, sale_place, product_type, company_id, branch_id, cash_desk_id, type_id, year_id,
                                    currency_id, finaler_id, signature_id, customer_id, final_at, signature_at,
                                    reference_factor_id, creator_id, number)
            VALUES ('sale_factor', 'branch', 'product', @Company, @Branch_Id, NULL, @Factor_Type_Id, @Fiscal_Year,
                    @Currency_Id, @Auth_User, @Auth_User, @Customer_Id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                    @Factor_Id, @Auth_User, Num);

            SET @New_Factor_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END IF;


        INSERT INTO Tb_Factor_Details (product_id, value, real_fee, fee, factor_id, creator_id, return_penalty_percent,
                                       return_penalty_price)
        VALUES (@Product_Id, @Value, @Real_Fee, @Real_Fee, @New_Factor_Id, @Auth_User, @Penalty_Percent,
                @Return_Penalty_Price);

        SET @New_Detail_Factor_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();


        INSERT INTO Tb_Factor_Detail_Serials (serial_id, detail_id)
        SELECT NV.Number, @New_Detail_Factor_Id FROM Numeric_Values NV;


        SELECT id INTO @Receipt_Remit_Type_Id FROM Tb_Receipt_Remit_Types WHERE name = 'return_of_sales';

        SET @Warehouse_Id = 0;
        SELECT id INTO @Warehouse_Id FROM Tb_Warehouses WHERE warehouse_branch_id = @Branch_Id LIMIT 1;


        IF(@Document_Id = 0)
        THEN
            SELECT document_number
            FROM Tb_Documents
            WHERE fiscal_year_id = @Fiscal_Year
            ORDER BY document_number DESC
            LIMIT 1
            INTO @Document_Number;
            SET @Document_Number = @Document_Number + 1;

            INSERT INTO Tb_Documents (type, factor_id, warehouse_id, receipt_remit_type_id, fiscal_year_id, document_number,
                                      creator_id)
            VALUES ('receipt', @New_Factor_Id, @Warehouse_Id, @Receipt_Remit_Type_Id, @Fiscal_Year, @Document_Number,
                    @Auth_User);

            SET @Document_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END IF;


        INSERT INTO Tb_Document_Details (product_id, value, confirmed_at, confirmed_by, creator_id, document_id)
        VALUES (@Product_Id, @Value, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), @Auth_User, @Auth_User, @Document_Id);

        SET @Document_Detail_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO Tb_Detail_Serial_Numbers (serial_number_id, detail_id, origin_cost_center_id, confirmed_at,
                                              confirmed_by)
        SELECT NV.Number, @Document_Detail_Id,NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),@Auth_User FROM Numeric_Values NV;


    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;

    SET @Type_Id = 0;
    SELECT id INTO @Type_Id FROM Tb_Payment_Types WHERE name = 'cash' LIMIT 1;

    INSERT INTO Tb_Receive_Payment (model_type, model_id, factor_id, type_id, receive_amount, payment_amount,year_id,creator_id)
    VALUES ('cashdesk', NULL, @New_Factor_Id, @Type_Id, 0, @Payment_Amount,@Fiscal_Year,@Auth_User);

    SET @Payment_Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    SELECT @Factor_Id as factor_id,@Payment_Id as payment_id,@Payment_Amount as payment_amount;

    COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: You will have to remove logical part by logical part of this procedure to have a better idea where is the problem. Also, can you coppy-paste the whole error or is this "Result consisted of more than one row" all you get ?

Comment: One of the `SELECT ... INTO variables` queries is returning multiple rows. If you're selecting into variables, it has to return just a single row.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `SELECT` if you're just setting a variable to an expression, e.g. `SET @Diff_Days = DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), @Date_At);`

Comment: I suspect it's the query that begins with `SELECT TP.is_returnable`. It has no `WHERE` clause, so it will return all the matching rows.